# Arcade/Computer Game: Alien crashed in graveyard, platform/side-scroller

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, arcade, linux

I'm looking for a game which I remember playing at an arcade, probably around 1995-2000. I also think I played it (or a very similar game) on PC under Linux ~5 years ago.

It's your typical platform/side-scroller game. The intro is of an alien in a flying saucer crashing in a grave-yard (and giving you the finger). When the game start, you must jump over gravestones and avoid skeletons and ghosts and get to the end of the graveyard/screen. I think the second level/screen is also in the graveyard. I've only played 2-3 times, and that's pretty much how far I got.

Does anybody remember the title of the game, or the title of the Linux version/clone?

Comment: I did some very deep searching on this and didn't turn up anything. Are you sure you're not convoluting multiple games together? What style is this game (3D rendering side scroller, or raster, or cartoonish)? Who are you playing as? The alien?

Comment: It's not impossible I'm mixing together. More likely I'm mixing an arcade game with a very similar PC-game (eg. the arcade dind't have the alien showing you the finger). It was raster.

Comment: Ghosts and Goblins (and the follow-up Ghouls and Ghosts) are probably too old to be the game you're looking for, but take a look at the gameplay and see if it's familiar. You definitely jump over tombstones in that game lol. There were a number of sequels, including much more advanced versions on consoles like the PSP.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsMiyr9M6lM